# MS Access Export XML but exclude ID element in vba

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, export

I'm trying to find a way to export all of my tables into a XML file but exclude just the ID column. What I can find from looking is that the best solution is to just make a query that has only the columns that need to exported. My problem is that I'm exporting several tables and the query would results in about a million records. So is there a way to leave my code to just export all the tables and exclude just the ID column? Here is my code

```
Do Until rsR.EOF
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
    Set objOtherTbls = Application.CreateAdditionalData
    objOtherTbls.Add "entry"
    objOtherTbls.Add "patch"
    objOtherTbls.Add "reference"
    objOtherTbls.Add "remediations"
    objOtherTbls.Add "scanners"
    objOtherTbls.Add "tempMitStrat"
    objOtherTbls.Add "vms"
    Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
                DataSource:="iavmNotice", _
                DataTarget:="C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Documents\iavms\" & rsR.Fields("iavmNoticeNumber").Value & " (ID " & rsR.Fields("count").Value & ").xml", _
                WhereCondition:="[iavmNoticeNumber] = '" & rsR.Fields("iavmNoticeNumber").Value & "'", _
                AdditionalData:=objOtherTbls

                rsR.MoveNext
                Loop
                rsR.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider removing the IDs using XSLT after original XML is exported by running the Identity Transform (copy document as is) and using empty templates on *ID* elements:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file or embedded VBA string with double quote escaping and using loadXML)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <!-- Removing IDs with Empty Templates (change to actual names) -->
  <xsl:template match="iavmNoticeID|entryID|patchID|referenceID|remediationsID|scannersID|tempMitStratID|vmsID"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**VBA**

```vb
Public Sub RunXSLT()
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Input.xml"
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT\SCript.xsl"

    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```